# How to create a code from comboboxes using substring in c# visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, substring

So I'm doing a coursework in school about a music school and one thing I want to do is to be able to create a tuition code (made up of 6 characters) from 3 entered values.
So cbInstrument is a combobox, cbLevel is also a combobox and rb10Lessons/rb20Lesoons are radio buttons. When the code is running I want to be able to create a tuitionCode from these values as I choose them so that the tuition code would show up in a label of that same form as I choose the information.

For example; if in running form for instrument I click 'Cello', TuitionCode Shows up as CEL. Then after that if I click Level as 'Grade 1', TuitionCode shows up as CELB. And then if I choose 10 lessons then TuitionCode = CELB10.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
private void Tuition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string code = "";
        string codePart1 = code.Substring(0, 3);
        string codePart2 = code.Substring(3, 1);
        string codePart3 = code.Substring(4, 2);

        if (cbInstrument.Text == "Cello")
        {
            codePart1 = "CEL";
        }
        else if (cbInstrument.Text == "Clarinet")
        {
            codePart1 = "CLA";
        }
        else if (cbInstrument.Text == "Double Bass")
        {
            codePart1 = "DBA";
        }


        if ((cbLevel.Text == "None") || (cbLevel.Text == "Grade 1") || (cbLevel.Text == "Grade 2"))
        {
            codePart2 = "B";
        }
        else if ((cbLevel.Text == "Grade 3") || (cbLevel.Text == "Grade 4") || (cbLevel.Text == "Grade 5"))
        {
            codePart2 = "I";
        }

        if (rb10Lessons.Checked)
        {
            codePart3 = "10";
        }
        else if (rb20Lessons.Checked)
        {
            codePart3 = "20";
        }

        lblTuitionCode.Text = code;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try concatenating those `codePart` variables? Also note: your substring on an `""` is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function ... `Subtring` will return a substring within a string: for example : "123456".Substring(2,1)" will return "3"

What you need is simply to aggregate your string :

```
code = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", codePart1, codePart2, codePart3);
```

that's it

Answer (score 1):

The return value of Substring is its own string, not a reference to part of the string passed to it.

C# 6 has a feature called string interpolation which looks like this:

`code = $"{codePart1}{codePart2}{codePart3}";`

You could also use `String.Format(...)` if your VS version doesn't support C# 6 features.

Comment: Nice feature ! Does it support intelliSence and refactoring ?

Comment: Yeah, you can even combine it with `@` for pre-formatted strings.